# tinymce init location script

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to find a solution for this for weeks and I'm finding answers all
over the internet but I do not know where and how to add this very short script.

I want to have plain text paste enabled on my frontend wordpress tinymce.

So people say use this

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "paste",
    paste_as_text: true
});
```

But I don't know where to put this script in.
The `class-wp-editor.php` does not have any tinymce.init config that I can find.
Would be great if I can solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use
[wp_editor()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/)
with a shortcode.

`tinymce` is part of [settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/_wp_editors/parse_settings/).

```
$settings = array( 'tinymce' => array('your_options') );
wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your respond.

Still I don't know how where to add this.
Do I need to add this to my function.php or a new .php file.
If so how can I make tinymce see this file?

This is the script I use to display the tinymce at the frontend.
With searching over the internet I added the 'paste as text' => true in,
but this does not help as the editor still paste in styled format.
Did I do this correct, if not, how to enable 'paste as text'?

```
<?php $cont = isset($post) ? $post->post_content : '';
                                            wp_editor(wpautop(stripslashes($cont)),'post_content', array(
                                                'paste_as_text' => true, 
                                                'textarea_name' => 'pack[post_content]',
                                                'teeny' => 1, 'media_buttons' => 0,
                                                'tinymce' => array('toolbar1' => 'bold,italic,underline,blockquote,strikethrough,bullist,link,unlink,media,mybutton'),
                                                'quicktags' => false, 'textarea_rows' => 15)); ?>
```